# How to disable method call if instance of object doesn't exist (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, debouncing

Is there a way to not call a method from the function object (instance of it) if that instance doesn't exist?

This is my function for sticky sidebar and it has 2 methods;
init() and updateSticky();

```
function stickySideBar(element, options = {}) {
    var _this = this;

   _this.init = function () {}

   _this.updateSticky = function (timeout) {
     //this is actually just a debouncer that calls init method
    }
}
```

I want to use this updateSticky on window resize

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    newsletterBlog.updateSticky();
    sideBarBlog.updateSticky();
    if ($(productsSticky.element).length > 0) {
        productsSticky.updateSticky();
    }
});
```

now I use if loop to check if an element exists but I would like to do that inside of the instance of that function

if i dont have if loop i get "Uncaught TypeError: e.updateSticky is not a function".

cheers

EDIT

here is the function

```
function stickySideBar(element, options = {}) {
    var _this = this;

    console.log("_this :>> ", _this);

    //declared element
    _this.debouncer;
    _this.element = element;

    if ($(_this.element).length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    // declared options
    _this.parentElementClass = options.parentElementClass;
    _this.wrapClass = options.wrapClass;
    _this.activeStickyClass = options.activeStickyClass;
    _this.top = options.top;
    _this.width = options.width;
    _this.activeBottomClass = options.activeBottomClass;
    _this.disableOnMobile = options.disableOnMobile ? options.disableOnMobile : true;

    _this.breakpoint = 992;

    _this.init = function () {

    };

    _this.updateSticky = function (timeout) {
        if ($(_this.element).length === 0) return;
        var timeoutVal = timeout ? timeout : 100;

        clearTimeout(_this.debouncer);
        _this.debouncer = setTimeout(function () {
            _this.init();
        }, timeoutVal);
    };

    return _this.init();
}
```

Comment: If I got it right, you can try `e.updateSticky && e.updateSticky()` or `e?.updateSticky?.()`

Comment: It should be down to the `updateSticky()` function to validate the existence of required elements (assuming they aren't being passed in as arguments, which appears not to be the case here) not the calling block.

Comment: My problem is not in elements, it is that the instance doesn't exist because it is on another page. I would like not to be  able to call the method if the instance dosen't exist